# Vagrant error with libvirt

Tags: vagrant, libvirt

I'm trying to set up vagrant for the first time in my life while following a tutorial. I'm using the VVCW box because I want to work with WordPress with it.
So I downloaded the zip file and unzip it on a folder at my /home and didn't change the default.yml file.

That is the result: (I'm on a Xubuntu 18.04)

`fabio@thinkpad:~/Vagrant/vccw$ vagrant up`

`Bringing machine 'vccw.test' up with 'libvirt' provider...`
`#<Thread:0x000055ef7b1cc6c0@/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:71 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    25: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in`block (2 levels) in run'
    24: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `action'
    23: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in`call'
    22: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:592:in `lock'
    21: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:202:in`block in action'
    20: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:227:in `action_raw'
    19: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in`run'
    18: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    17: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in`block in run'
    16: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    15: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
    14: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    13: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
    12: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:31:in `call'
    11: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in`call'
    10: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:52:in `call'
     9: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:170:in`to_app'
     8: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:170:in `new'
     7: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:20:in`initialize'
     6: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:20:in `map'
     5: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:20:in`block in initialize'
     4: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:90:in `finalize_action'
     3: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:90:in`new'
     2: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.0.43/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/create_networks.rb:26:in `initialize'
     1: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.0.43/lib/vagrant-libvirt/driver.rb:40:in`connection'
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.0.43/lib/vagrant-libvirt/driver.rb:43:in `rescue in connection': Error while connecting to libvirt: Error making a connection to libvirt URI qemu:///system?no_verify=1&keyfile=/home/fabio/.ssh/id_rsa: (VagrantPlugins::ProviderLibvirt::Errors::FogLibvirtConnectionError)
Call to virConnectOpen failed: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
Error while connecting to libvirt: Error making a connection to libvirt URI qemu:///system?no_verify=1&keyfile=/home/fabio/.ssh/id_rsa:
Call to virConnectOpen failed: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory`

I just tried with another box and the same error happened.

Someone can help me?
Thanks a lot!

Edit-1: looking for the error elsewhere, I just installed vagrant-libvirt plugin.

`fabio@thinkpad:~/Vagrant/teste$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
Installing the 'vagrant-libvirt' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-libvirt (0.0.43)'!`

But when I did `vagrant up`, the same error was shown. :(

Edit-2: I followed instructions and did that:

`$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
$ sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils virt-manager
$ sudo adduser fabio libvirt
$ sudo adduser fabio libvirt-qemu
$ sudo /etc/init.d/libvirtd restart`

The error persists the same... :(

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the issue

I'm using VirtualBox version 6.0 from the repositories and the Vagrant version of the repositories isn't the latest version so the conflict.

So first I removed vagrant with

`sudo apt --purge remove vagrant`

`sudo apt autoremove`

After that I downloaded the final release of Vagrant from [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) and installed:

`sudo dpkg -i vagrant_x.x.x_x86_64.deb`

The installation was pretty fast and so I call for the Vagrant version to be sure it was installed:

`vagrant version`

I got this output:

`Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:`

`The plugins failed to initialize correctly. This may be due to manual
modifications made within the Vagrant home directory. Vagrant can
attempt to automatically correct this issue by running:`

`vagrant plugin repair`

`If Vagrant was recently updated, this error may be due to incompatible
versions of dependencies. To fix this problem please remove and re-install
all plugins. Vagrant can attempt to do this automatically by running:`

`vagrant plugin expunge --reinstall`

`Or you may want to try updating the installed plugins to their latest
versions:`

`vagrant plugin update`

`Error message given during initialization: Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'vagrant-libvirt (= 0.0.43)'`

So I decided (actually remembered) to uninstall vagrant-libvirt:

`sudo apt --purge remove vagrant-libvirt`

Did a `sudo apt update` - just in case...

and `vagrant up` again.

And It works!!!!!!!  :)

Comment: Worked like a charm running Ubuntu 18.04, VirtualBox 6.0.10.  Upgraded to Vagrant 2.2.5 and the problems disappeared.  Many thanks FabioB!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error starting with `Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:` and ending with `Error message given during initialization: Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'vagrant-libvirt (= 0.12.0)'`.

Additionally, I had the issue of `Plugin 'vagrant-proxyconf' not found.`

I was already on the newest Vagrant version (2.3.6), so it was not an issue of having a too old Vagrant version. libvirt seemed installed and active as a virsh command worked:

```
# virsh list --all
 Id   Name   State
--------------------
```

As you did, I tried `dnf remove vagrant-libvirt`, but got `No match for argument: vagrant-libvirt`

After reading [vagrant libvirt documentation](https://vagrant-libvirt.github.io/vagrant-libvirt/installation.html), an older version (2.2.19) of Vagrant was installed and this worked! It seems like vagrant-libvirt is not yet supported on Vagrant version 2.6.6 yet. **Thus, using an older Vagrant version <2.3 is the solution.**